# How do i mock a service that is inside a controller, and deals with promises?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this simple controller:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('feedsSnapshotsApp').controller('feedEditCtrl', function ($scope, lakesService) {

        $scope.getDataForLakes= function(){
            lakesService.query().then(function(result){
                $scope.model.lakes = result.lakes;
            });
        };
})
;
```

I want to do the following:

I want to test if the function works correctly:
 I want to mock the service in my test unit, and return a mocked promise for the "lakesService.query"  to do it's thing, How should i achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: you need to inject $q to mock a promise, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scope;
beforeEach(module('feedsSanpshotApp')); 
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.model = {
        lakes: undefined
    };
    var lakesServiceMock = {
        query: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve('modelLakes'); // put the result you want to be resolved here
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    };
    var mock = {
        $scope: scope,
        lakesService: lakesServiceMock
    };
    $controller('feedEditCtrl', mock);
}));

it('test', function (done) {
    scope.getDataForLakes();
    expect(scope.model.lakes).toBe('modelLakes');
    done();
});
```

Comment: I still can't test out an "it" with the query...How should i check if $scope.model.lakes is with something that came back with the mock?

Comment: you just need to define `scope` where `it` and `beforeEach` can access, and pass it to mock.$scope in `beforeEach`. after that in your `it`, just call `scope.getDataForLakes()` and check `scope.model.lakes`